# Save CSV file into specific directory

Tags: php, arrays

**I create a CSV file from a array but not able to save it into specific directory.**

***PHP function likes for create csv from array***

```
public function outputCsv($fileName, $assocDataArray)
{
    ob_clean();
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $fileName);    
    if(isset($assocDataArray['0'])){
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        fputcsv($fp, array_keys($assocDataArray['0']));
        foreach($assocDataArray AS $values){
            fputcsv($fp, $values);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
    ob_flush();
}
```

***Array Like***

```
$data = array(
    array( 'item' => 'Server', 'cost' => 10000, 'approved by' => 'Joe'),
    array( 'item' => 'Mt Dew', 'cost' => 1.25, 'approved by' => 'John')
    array( 'item' => 'IntelliJ IDEA', 'cost' => 500, 'approved by' => 'James'),
);
```

***Get output from this function:***

```
outputCsv('expenses.csv', $data);
```

**Provide me good solution according to this function**

Comment: Side note: Please don't use blockquote for text. They have a special purpose. I edited it along with your other posts that contained it.

Comment: Special purpose for what can you provide me an example, where I can use that.

Comment: https://html.com/tags/blockquote/ -- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250415/do-we-need-a-new-markdown-formatting-for-indented-boxed-text-for-preambles-r --- it's for code, errors, quoting a site/person, just not for "regular text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file where you want to save, with `fopen`

```
$fp = fopen('path/to/file', 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is to save the file in the client.
If your file is saving automatically in the default Download folder, that is a configuration in your browser, not in the code.

Comment: Yeah..I knew that that's why I need that to save the csv file in specific directory.